# DJI SDK for Windows

Tags: dji-sdk

Where do I find the DJI SDK for Windows that was announced at Build 2018?

I'd like to play with my Mavic Air, but the sample UWP app requires the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK is now downloadable (since end of Oktober, beginning of November 2018?) from https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/
Only needs a DJI account, I think.

(Also, the sample code that's downloadable from github basically includes the four SDK files - two DLLs, an XML and a winmd file - in the Windows-SDK-master\WSDK Libraries\SDK dll subfolder. I have not gotten anything around all this to work though..)

Answer (score 1):

The WindowsSDK was given as an exclusivity to Build attendees. We will make it available on developer.dji.com soon.

At this point the best way to get it is to sign up on the website and wait for the email announcing it.

Comment: I did attend the Build 2018 and DJI workshops. I don't recall getting any special download link etc

Comment: Check your mails and spam box, on the Tuesday of the event in the morning the email was sent.